# Sweave -- Must Always Recompile Every R Script?

Tags: sweave

I am writing a large document using a Latex, WinEdt, RStudio and Sweave.  I have a large number of graphs that use SWeave code blocks (>30).  Many of these blocks read in large data files from disk.  Most days I work on on 2-3 blocks at a time.  However, no matter how minor a change I make to the R code, every time I compile, the entire document must run through R.  This can take 5-10 minutes.

I guess what I am looking for is a combination of a C/C++ make file and R/Sweave.  Does such a concept exist or am I being too needy?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you know about the cacheing options? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538367/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628665. I believe to use with Sweave there are extra hoops to jump through but that it's built into knitr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using RStudio with knitr package just put `<<cache=TRUE>>=` in those chunks you want to skip during recompilation.

Comment: Unless there is a new development I have missed, plain *Sweave* does not support caching of results. As Aaron commented, the options are to use [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) or go through "extra hoops" to add caching to Sweave.

Comment: Oh, you are right! Using Sweave in R studio with knitr package just comes so natural that it was my first thought. And it is simply no fuss at all. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks all, after reading up on Knitr and cache this appears to be exactly what I wanted.